# How to uninstall the driver by using command prompt in Win 10?

Tags: command-prompt

Every time, I try to uninstall the graphic card. I have to open Device Manager and go to Display adapter to click the uninstall the driver thing.

So I want to make it be automated. But I am stuck on how to uninstall the driver from cmd. When I type pnputil -d -f name.inf. (or pnputil -f -d name.inf, I forgot which one is correct but I tried both) It always failed and outputted "pnputil deleting drive package failed: devices are presently installed using the specified INF"

Does anyone know how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 7):

In order  to remove driver package you need to run at first 
pnputil -e
After that you need to find the oem.inf of the package.
and the uninstall will be
pnputil -f -d oem#.inf

Answer (score 1):

From a recovery tool, win10 bootable usb.
go on repair system,
access to cmd

and do these three things

1- Check drivers installed (check if e: fi where win located)

`dism /image:e:\ /get-drivers`

2- Get mode info about the driver (example: driver:oem1.inf)

`dism /image:e:\ /get-driverinfo /driver:oem1.inf`

3- Remove identify driver

`dism /image:e:\ /remove-driver /driver:oem1.inf`

From https://pureinfotech.com/uninstall-driver-recovery-environment-windows-10/

Comment: need to path over windows\system32 first

Comment: If you're trying to modify your current Windows operating system whilst logged in, replace ``/image:e:\``  with `/online`